# query parameter passing to internal/embedded pages using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I extremely need to pass parameters to internal pages like from div to another in jqm. is this feature available in jqm??? counting on ur professional answers as usual.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess duplicate of [How to pass and get Parameters between two Pages in Jquery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582781/how-to-pass-and-get-parameters-between-two-pages-in-jquery-mobile) or [Passing parameters to a page-id in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile/8295488#8295488) or many more helps if you google with "jquery mobile passing parameters between pages".

still have issue with passing parameter? -> please share sample of your code which you have tried.

Comment: Thank you Hardik, I did google it and I got arround 4 answers. I will try which one works for me and will post the answer on SO. Thanks again.