# JQuery mobile + Phonegap with ajax loading a multipage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an html file with 3 empty pages (appAnotado, appCompilado and appOriginal).

```
<div id="appAnotado" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
    <div id="divDestino" data-mini="true">
        <div id="visoes" data-role="navbar">
        </div>
        <div id="divTexto" data-mini="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="appCompilado" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
    <div id="divDestinoCompilado" data-mini="true">
        <div id="visoesCompilado" data-role="navbar">
        </div>
        <div id="divTextoCompilado" data-mini="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="appOriginal" data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
    <div id="divAtoDestinoOriginal" data-mini="true">
        <div id="visoesOriginal" data-role="navbar">
        </div>
        <div id="divTextoOriginal" data-mini="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I fill these pages with 3 ajax calls from 3 external URL. Each page is filled according to your alias.

```
<script>
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#appAnotado",function () {
    var id = 10;
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.ajax({
        url :'http://myApp.action?id=' + id + '&visao=anotado',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : "html",
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(dados) {
            $('#visoes').html(jQuery(dados).find('#visoes').html());
            $('#divTexto').html(jQuery(dados).find('#divTexto').html());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url :'http://myApp.action?id=' + id + '&visao=compilado',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : "html",
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(dados) {
            $('#visoesCompilado').html(jQuery(dados).find('#visoes').html());
            $('#divTextoCompilado').html(jQuery(dados).find('#divTexto').html());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url :'http://myApp.action?id=' + id + '&visao=original',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : "html",
        data : formData,
        cache : false,
        crossDomain: true,
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success : function(dados) {
            $('#visoesOriginal').html(jQuery(dados).find('#visoes').html());
            $('#divTextoOriginal').html(jQuery(dados).find('#divTexto').html());
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Views (alias) are defined in a navbar. And this code is brought by the external URL.

```
<div id="visoes" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="anotado10" class="ui-btn-active" href="appAnotado" >Anotado</a></li>
        <li><a id="publicado10" href="appCompilado" >Compilado</a></li>
        <li><a id="original10" href="appOriginal" >Original</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I run the application, only the first page is displayed (this is correct), but when I click on the other views (alias) momentarily appears the message `"error loading page"`.

I tried using the properties `rel = "external"` or `data-ajax = "false"` found this **[jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)** but it did not work.

Comment: `href="#appAnotado"` you forgot hashtag in all `href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omar, Thanks for your attention.
I solved the problem of change in the pages following the example this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582781/how-to-pass-and-get-parameters-between-two-pages-in-jquery-mobile).

Added the hashtags `'#appAnotado'` as suggested by Omar:

```
<div id="visoes" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="anotado10" class="ui-btn-active" href="#appAnotado" >Anotado</a></li>
        <li><a id="publicado10" href="#appCompilado" >Compilado</a></li>
        <li><a id="original10" href="#appOriginal" >Original</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And added the function that retrieves the id for each view as suggested by Phill Pafford:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
$(document).on( "pagebeforeshow", "#appAnotado", function( e ) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    $.ajax({
        url :'http://myApp.action?id=' + getParameterByName('id'),
[...]
```

Only the hashtag did not solve the problem.
I think maybe the application was broken by error parameter passing. And with the above function `getParameterByName(name)` the problem was solved.

Still it was necessary to fix the `listview` that calls this page:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <a href="?id=10#appAnotado" rel="external"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Despite all the pages are in the same html file using the property `rel="external"` is fundamental.

I apologize for thinking that the problem was only on changing pages.

Comment: Great, you should mark your answer as correct answer not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

To link a page in single-file temple, add hashtag before page's id, this way `<a href=#page_id>Page</a>`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8DKQq/)**

```html
<div id="visoes" data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="anotado10" class="ui-btn-active" href="#appAnotado">Anotado</a></li>
    <li><a id="publicado10" href="#appCompilado">Compilado</a></li>
    <li><a id="original10" href="#appOriginal">Original</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Omar, Thanks for answering.
I added the hashtag in all "href", but it did not work.
Now no longer appears the message "error loading page".

Comment: @leonardo this is weird. Try JS solution then `$('#button_id').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var goTo = $(this).attr('href'); $.mobile.changePage(goTo); });`

Comment: I added the JS with a `alert()`, but he was not called. The page was not displayed. No error appeared. 
`$('#original36048').on('click', function (e) {
 alert('original36048');
 e.preventDefault();
 var goTo = $(this).attr('href');
 $.mobile.changePage(goTo); 
});`

Comment: I tested in your [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8DKQq/) and works fine. In my app no yet. The ajax call may be responsible for this?

Comment: @leonardo if you have all pages in one file (html file) it should work normally. What are you getting exactly?